# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain in swift

Tags: swift

When I send data to the server Post is perfectly fine and complete works but an error

erro return :

```
 B
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

return data from server perfectly

data =

> [   {
>       "$id": "1",
>       "Id": 14,
>       "Source": 23,
>       "Destination_": 21,
>       "Exclusive": false,
>       "AdultPrice": "70766",
>       "ChildPrice": "77076",
>       "BabyPrice": "54109",
>       "VetranPrice": "118664",
>       "DepartureDate": "1997-09-25T00:00:00",
>       "ArrivalDate": "2001-03-24T00:00:00",
>       "TrainTypeId": 1,
>       "NumberofSeats": 153   } ]

You can tell what is the reason?

```
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: todosUrlRequest)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=uft-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
        //3
        let newTodo = [
            "NumberOfPassenger": tedat,
            "Source": cityIDSource,
            "Destination": cityIDDestination,
            "DapartureDate": raftDate,
            "TicketType": typeTrainID,
            "TravelType": 6,
            "CloseDoor": copeqtar
            ]
        print(newTodo)
        //4
        let jsonTodo: NSData
        do {
            jsonTodo = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(newTodo, options: [])
            request.HTTPBody = jsonTodo

        } catch {
            print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
            return
        }

        print(jsonTodo)


        request.HTTPBody = jsonTodo
        //5
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            // statusResponse
            if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

                if statusCode == 200 {
                    print(response)
                    //6
                    print(data)
                    if data != nil {

                        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

                    }

                    guard let responseData = data else {
                        return
                    }
                    self.dataRecive = responseData

                    print("currect")
                }else{
                    print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
                    print(error)


                }

            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                actInd.stopAnimating()

            }

        }
        task.resume()
```